# Can't login to a certain user in ubuntu 16.04(black screen)

Tags: unity, login, users

when i try to login to a certain user in Ubuntu 16.04 a black screen appears, however i can login to other users, and i can login to this user when i enter recovery mode. 
I have not changed any drivers, is there is any to get it working back?

The result of

```
ls -la .Xauthority
```

is

```
-rw------- 1 mostafa mostafa 156 سبت  6 16:28 .Xauthority
```

Comment: add into the question results of `ls -la .Xauthority` This needs to be executed from the home of that user (but can be done with another user).

Comment: i have edited the question

Answer (score 1):

With "login" you mean login into your desktop?
Sometimes this is caused by wrong owner.
Can you login on the console? (i guess, yes)

I suggest doing

```
sudo chown -R mostafa /home/mostafa
sudo chown -R mostafa /home/mostafa/.[^.]*  # for the hidden files
```

That will change the owner of ALL files in your home directory to mostafa.
The try again to login into your desktop.